# Spaces every so many characters

Tags: java, for-loop, stringbuilder

I know that this code would put in a space between every character...

```
String nospaces = encrypt.replaceAll("\\s+","");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (char c: nospaces.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append(c).append(" ");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
```

If you wanted to put in a space after a certain number of characters, e.g. 5, how would you do that?

Comment: You could start with that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `replaceAll` in this as well:

```
 String withSpaces = nospaces.replaceAll("(.{5})", "$1 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like this (untested) :

```
char[] arr = nospaces.toCharArray();

for (int i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {   
    if (i % 5 == 0) { // after 5 characters, add space 
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    sb.append(arr[i);
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question, what is the c in the sb.append at the end?

Comment: @mattsud2000 Sure, it's `arr[i]`

Comment: And, of course, you need to start with `0` (maybe, after that you'll need to change condition to `i % 5 == 4`)